# Execute the function automatically in 30 seconds, if the button is not pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add the following functionality to my web page: if a user has not pressed the 'Accept' button during 30 seconds, then `$('#popupBoxAccept').click( function() {..}` is executed automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadPopupBox();
});

function loadPopupBox() {   // to load the Popupbox 
    $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");     
}

$('#popupBoxAccept').click( function() {            
    //...
});

$('#popupBoxDecline').click( function() {           
    //...
});

<div id="popup_box">
    <a id="popupBoxAccept">Accept</a>
    <a id="popupBoxDecline">Decline</a>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Vch/)*

```
var tim = setTimeout(function(){
    $('#popupBoxAccept').click();
},30000);
```

And inside the *manual* click:

```
$('#popupBoxAccept').click(function(){
     clearTimeout(tim);
      // ........
});
```

And as suggested by @Elias:

```
$('#popupBoxDecline').click( function() {
    clearTimeout(tim);           
    //...
});
```

Comment: Elegant and simple solution. Thx.

Comment: @YouKuper sorry my mistake, I had a typo seTimeout now changed to setTimeout ! my bad :)

Comment: @Roko: Mustn't forget to clear the timeout in the `#popupBoxDecline` handler, too.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yeah, great suggestion.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem is right. In case if you click 'Decline' the timer handler will fire anyway. I actually have the same problem :)

Comment: @VisioN sure! I missed that. Edited the Answer

Answer (score 4):

One simple option is to use a flag and `setTimeout` function:

```
var clicked = false;
$("#popupBoxAccept").click(function() {
    clicked = true;
    //...
});

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!clicked) {
        $("#popupBoxAccept").click();
    }
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
setTimeOut(function(){
  $('#popupBoxAccept').click( function() {            
    //...
});
}, 30000);
```

Comment: This code just binds a click handler to the accept button 30secs after the page loaded... It doesn't even fire the click event...

Answer (score 1):

Just set a timeout:

```
var tim;//global, I'll provide a (more complex) solution that doesn't need them, too
function loadPopupBox() {   // to load the Popupbox 
    $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
    tim = setTimeout(function()
    {
        $('#popup_box').click();
    },30000);
}

$('#popupBoxAccept').click( function() {            
    clearTimeout(tim);
});
```

now, without the use of *EVIL* global variables:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    (function(popup,accept,decline)
    {
        popup.fadeIn("slow");
        var tim = setTimeout(function()
        {
            accept.click();//<-- access to reference is preserved
        },30000);
        accept.click(function()
        {
            clearTimeout(tim);
            //do accept stuff
        });
        decline.click(function()
        {
            clearTimeout(tim);//<-- need that here, too!
            //do decline stuff
        });
    })($('#popup_box'),$('#popupBoxAccept'),$('#popupBoxDecline'));
    //pass all 3 elements as argument --> less typing, and is more efficient:
    //the DOM is only searched once for each element
});
```

Why is this useful? Simple: you can now use `var tim` in another context, without loosing the reference to your timeout. Closure, the name says it all: all the variables and references are neatly bundled together in the same scope, and cannot be accessed but from within the scope they are declared:

```
var foo = (function()
{
    var invisible = 'Now you see me';
    return function()
    {
        return invisible;
    }
};
console.log(invisible);//<-- undefined
var invisible = 'Now you don\'t';
console.log(foo());//<-- Now you see me
console.log(invisible);//Now you don\'t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your `$(document).ready()` call:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if(!clicked) {
        $('#popupBoxAccept').click();
    }
}, 30000);
```

Then change

```
$('#popupBoxAccept').click( function() {
    //...
});
```

to

```
var clicked = false;
$('#popupBoxAccept').click( function() {
    clicked = true;
    //...
});
```